# Creating a time series object in R with non-uniform time data for ets()

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, forecasting

I have a set of data that spans 6 years with data points 3 times of each year. I am trying to create an object to feed into R's forecasting package but I need the data to appear like the following but am not able to figure out the frequency or deltat logic on the ts().

```
2002 23 24 19
2003 03 23 20
2004 18 18 19
2005 12 21 29
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) showing the structure your raw data, and your code (that's not "working") so that others can reproduce your steps, errors etc and answer your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `frequency=3` as a parameter to `ts()`:

```
library(forecast)
foo <- ts(c(23,24,19,03,23,20,18,18,19,12,21,29),
    frequency=3,start=2002)
model <- ets(foo)
plot(forecast(model,h=6))
```

[image: forecast]